# How to extract specific string from HTML Element in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<input id="WD01B3" ct="CB" lsdata="{2:'WD01B4',4:'Any',20:'\x7b\x22WDA_TYPE\x22\x3a\x22DROPDOWN_BY_KEY\x22,\x22WDA_ID\x22\x3a\x22ABCA950297D2C0C432BAB9BBF5A1BB48.07.MAINVIEW._0120\x22,\x22ENABLED\x22\x3a\x22X\x22,\x22KEYS\x22\x3a\x5b\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Any\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22AC\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Action\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22AP\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Application\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22CA\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Catalog\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22DO\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Data\x20Object\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22EX\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Expression\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22ET\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Expression\x20Type\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22FI\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Filter\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22FU\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Function\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22RU\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Rule\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22RS\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Ruleset\x22\x7d\x5d,\x22VISIBLE\x22\x3a\x2202\x22,\x22WIDTH\x22\x3a\x22100px\x22,\x22SCRIPT_METHODS\x22\x3a\x7b\x22setBackgroundColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderRadius\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderStyle\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderWidth\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontFamily\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontSize\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontStyle\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontWeight\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setTextDecoration\x22\x3a\x22client\x22\x7d\x7d'}" lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsField__input" readonly="" value="Any" aria-roledescription="Select" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-describedby=" ARIA_CB_TUT" aria-readonly="false" style="width:100px;">
```

Requirement: Extract `ABCA950297D2C0C432BAB9BBF5A1BB48.07.MAINVIEW._0120` from the above HTML Element data.

I have `ABCA950297D2C0C432BAB9BBF5A1BB48.07.MAINVIEW.`, how can I get the remaining string/number using JavaScript?

Comment: I recommend posting the code that you have tried.

Comment: How did you get the second string? And why can't you use that to get the rest of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using REGEX you can get the string in between WDA_ID and the \x22 immediately after.

```js
const WD01B3 = document.querySelector("#WD01B3");

lsdata = WD01B3.getAttribute("lsdata")
const matches = lsdata.match(/WDA_ID\\x22\\x3a\\x22(.*?)\\x22/);
let ID = matches[1]
console.log(ID)
```

```html
<input id="WD01B3" ct="CB" lsdata="{2:'WD01B4',4:'Any',20:'\x7b\x22WDA_TYPE\x22\x3a\x22DROPDOWN_BY_KEY\x22,\x22WDA_ID\x22\x3a\x22ABCA950297D2C0C432BAB9BBF5A1BB48.07.MAINVIEW._0120\x22,\x22ENABLED\x22\x3a\x22X\x22,\x22KEYS\x22\x3a\x5b\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Any\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22AC\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Action\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22AP\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Application\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22CA\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Catalog\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22DO\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Data\x20Object\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22EX\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Expression\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22ET\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Expression\x20Type\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22FI\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Filter\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22FU\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Function\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22RU\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Rule\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22RS\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Ruleset\x22\x7d\x5d,\x22VISIBLE\x22\x3a\x2202\x22,\x22WIDTH\x22\x3a\x22100px\x22,\x22SCRIPT_METHODS\x22\x3a\x7b\x22setBackgroundColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderRadius\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderStyle\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderWidth\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontFamily\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontSize\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontStyle\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontWeight\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setTextDecoration\x22\x3a\x22client\x22\x7d\x7d'}" lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsField__input" readonly="" value="Any" aria-roledescription="Select" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-describedby=" ARIA_CB_TUT" aria-readonly="false" style="width:100px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

What about getting the the element by ID WD01B3 -- Grabbing the `lsdata` as string -- Convert that to object and do it natively?

```js
var js = {2:'WD01B4',4:'Any',20:'\x7b\x22WDA_TYPE\x22\x3a\x22DROPDOWN_BY_KEY\x22,\x22WDA_ID\x22\x3a\x22ABCA950297D2C0C432BAB9BBF5A1BB48.07.MAINVIEW._0120\x22,\x22ENABLED\x22\x3a\x22X\x22,\x22KEYS\x22\x3a\x5b\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Any\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22AC\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Action\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22AP\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Application\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22CA\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Catalog\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22DO\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Data\x20Object\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22EX\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Expression\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22ET\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Expression\x20Type\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22FI\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Filter\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22FU\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Function\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22RU\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Rule\x22\x7d,\x7b\x22key\x22\x3a\x22RS\x22,\x22value\x22\x3a\x22Ruleset\x22\x7d\x5d,\x22VISIBLE\x22\x3a\x2202\x22,\x22WIDTH\x22\x3a\x22100px\x22,\x22SCRIPT_METHODS\x22\x3a\x7b\x22setBackgroundColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderRadius\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderStyle\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setBorderWidth\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontColor\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontFamily\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontSize\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontStyle\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setFontWeight\x22\x3a\x22client\x22,\x22setTextDecoration\x22\x3a\x22client\x22\x7d\x7d'}


var WD = JSON.parse(js['20']).WDA_ID
console.log ( WD  );
```

Comment: The value inside the `lsdata` attribute is bad JSON. The OP would have to find a way to clean it up before being able to "convert that to object".

Comment: Sounds like OP has 2 issues.  The JSON needs repaired in order to do this "correctly". --  I merely was pointing out, that given we have good JSON, we can do it natively...  Which seems much more preferable than parsing it apart with regex IMHO